# Control size of extensible parentheses and bracket

Tags: formatting, input

Consider `\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[f,0]\)((a,b])`.  I would want that typeset something like
$$f^0((a,b])$$
or maybe
$$f^0\Big((a,b]\Big)$$
Instead it formats like
$$f^0((a,b\Big]\Big)$$
presumably because MMA doesn't realize that the `]` is supposed to pair with the inner `(`.

How can I get one of the first two options?  Manual tweaking is ok (how to manually tweak extensible symbols?), or custom option definitions.

Comment: First of all, let us clarify, do I understand correctly, that OP speaks about such objects as e.g. InlineFormula, DisplayFormula, or DisplayFormulaNumbered?                               If yes, I think it is an important question. I would like to put it in a broader context: How one can control the sizes of the parentheses in formulas? The way to select the object in question and then use Menu/Format/Size requires too many clicks. So, how to easily make parentheses (brackets) with the desired size?

Comment: what is the context here? Are you just using Mathematica for typesetting? Is this something that will go into text cell? Or will be actual code? I never used Mathematica for typesetting myself. I just use it for programming and try to stick to plain text normal code and not use fancy typesetting characters. But use `TeXForm` to generate the Latex I need.

Comment: @Nasser Mma, indeed, can be used for typesetting. Not for publication, of course. For many years, making lots of analytic calculations I use Mma for keeping my results together with their explanations and the corresponding Mma code. In such cases, I often need to show some mathematical expressions in a TraditionalForm as DisplayFormulaNumbered or DisplayFormula. It is very important to see the expressions in this form to be able to decide on the next step of calculations. For people who use this approach, all tricks to make a better visualization of the formulas are important.

Comment: How do you want to create your object? Is it acceptable to define some MakeBoxes rules for an object that will look the way you want, or is this something you just want to type in using 2D input?

Comment: MakeBoxes is acceptable. My related kludge is `Row@{Superscript[f,0],RawBoxes@"(",RawBoxes@"(",a,b,RawBoxes@"]",RawBoxes@")"}`. I don't know much about boxes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can tell Mathematica to match <kbd>]</kbd> with <kbd>(</kbd> by using a [`TagBox`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TagBox), e.g.:

```
CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], {InputAliases, "]]"}] = TagBox["]", #&, SyntaxForm->")"];
```

Then, using <kbd>esc</kbd> <kbd>]</kbd> <kbd>]</kbd> <kbd>esc</kbd> instead of just <kbd>]</kbd> produces:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the correction of wording.  This strategy is more what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

Several years ago, there was a post on this site that probably answers your question. Unfortunately, I did not record the author or the title of that post. Within the approach of that old post a palette is created to insert all possible pairs of parentheses. Below I reproduce the code from that post:

```
CreatePalette[
 Column[{Style[
    Grid[Join[
      Partition[
       Map[PasteButton[
          Style[RawBoxes@
            RowBox@Insert[#, "\[SelectionPlaceholder]", 2], 
           FontSize -> 14, SpanMaxSize -> Infinity]] &, 
        Most@Tuples[{{"", "\[LeftBracketingBar]", "{", "(", "[", 
            ""}, {"", "\[RightBracketingBar]", "}", ")", "]", ""}}]], 
       4]], Spacings -> {0, 0}]]}], WindowTitle -> "Brackets", 
 Magnification -> 1.5]
```

The only problem here is that they are all of the same size, 14. I would like to be able to choose the size that I select myself.
Maybe, one can do it as follows:

```
CreatePalette[
 Manipulate[
  Column[{Style[
     Grid[Join[
       Partition[
        Map[PasteButton[
           Style[RawBoxes@
             RowBox@Insert[#, "\[SelectionPlaceholder]", 2], 
            FontSize -> sz, SpanMaxSize -> Infinity]] &, 
         Most@Tuples[{{"", "\[LeftBracketingBar]", "{", "(", "[", 
             ""}, {"", "\[RightBracketingBar]", "}", ")", "]", ""}}]],
         4]], Spacings -> {0, 0}]]}], {{sz, 12, "Parentheses size"}, 
   Range[12, 28, 2]}], WindowTitle -> "Brackets", 
 Magnification -> 1.5]
```

[image]

I hope this helps.

Have fun!