# Adapt size of brackets in text mode

Tags: output-formatting, display, text-formatting

In text mode, i.e. characters enclosed by " ", brackets do not adapt to the content. How can I achieve this? Actually I want to write a text that includes formulas. Without " " the variables are differently colored, depending if they are assigned or not. With " " they have the same color but brackets look disgusting.

[image]

Comment: This https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/258436/control-size-of-extensible-parentheses-and-bracket/258437#258437 can answer your question.

Comment: Isn't the inbuilt way just as you show and unsatisfactory to you? Here's another way: https://i.stack.imgur.com/a8lln.png -- is it inbuilt enough?

Comment: Here's a simpler code that achieves the desired effect: `"\!\((\*FractionBox[\(a\), \(b\)])\)"`

Answer (score 3):

Following the comments one has to place such expressions not within " " but in an inline cell that can be get by Strg+9

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In V13, you can also use Insert > Inline TeX Input (CTRL-4):

```
   " $\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)$ "
(*  ^ Insert > Inline TeX Input after typing " *)
(*                             ^ click outside TeX box to continue *)
```

and it will be typeset for you.